# What is the thing in jQuery Mobile that is reading "data-..." and replacing with DOM elements?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

jQuery mobile is reading through and replacing my DOM with it's own DOM.  I have the source of jQuery and jQuery Mobile open; where can I find the thing that is doing the reading and replacing?

The reason I want to learn about this feature is because I'm asynchronously injecting my own DOM and I want to run the jQuery Mobile "compiler" again so it renders my new DOM in jQuery Mobile's style.

Comment: `refresh()`was just made for that.

Comment: Sweet, thanks for the information!  I'll see what's going on in the source for refresh().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The thing](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084787/) is not easy to pin down. From JQM 1.4 you can have a look at all JQM content widgets and check out which functions are run when widget option `enhanced` is not set - usually that should be inside  an `_enhance()`

As for reading and writing `data-foo`, at the end of the day it will be your JavaScript `get/setAttribute` methods with some modifications for namespaces.

If you inject your own DOM, you can either
- inject pre-enhanced markup ~ no `data-`attributes, but finished contents (you should leave `data-` attributes should you want to change any widget options
- inject non-enhanced markup = just plain HTML with `data-`attributes.

In both cases you will need to call `enhanceWithin()` on the parent(!) which includes your dynamically added content. In the first case, JQM then only creates the widget objects. In the 2nd case, JQM creates the necessary markup and widget objects (slower).

Comment: Good point!  That makes a lot of sense, and now I'm kind of face-palming myself.  It's so obvious now that you say it: if I simply get the 'compiled' (aka post-enhanced markup) version of the code I'm after, then I don't need JQM to do anything.

Thanks for the response. I'll try to remember to think outside the API next time :)

Comment: Please mark as correct if the answer is correct. Also make sure to still call `enhancedWithin()` to create the JQM widget objects (not HTML source). These enable things like refreshing a listview. To "see" those object in Firebug, use something like [Firequery](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firequery/)